# Could anyone provides me two Restcomm accounts

Tags: restcomm

I hava registered RestcommONE account for many days,but RestComm administer still not validate my account creation request. Could anyone provides me two Restcomm accounts to learn how to use Restcomm-android-sdk.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. Your account should have been approved within a day or two. Please send an email to support@telestax.com from the email address you used to sign up, so they can look into the issue for you ;)